# Ansible - How to loop on a list and make split then assign the results to another list

Tags: ansible

I have ansible list variable

```
- sites:
    - x.domain.com.ex
    - y.domain.com.ex
    - z.domain.com.ex
```

I need to make two variables as follows:
list with the first level
x
y
z
and anther one with just the rest of domain name "domain.com.ex"

Your help is highly appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example, put the below declarations into the *vars*

```yaml
hostnames: "{{ sites|map('split', '.')|
                     map('first')|list }}"
domains: "{{ sites|map('reverse')|
                   map('splitext')|
                   map('first')|
                   map('reverse')|list }}"
```

give (abridged)

```yaml
hostnames:
  - x
  - y
  - z

domains:
  - domain.com.ex
  - domain.com.ex
  - domain.com.ex
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    sites:
      - x.domain.com.ex
      - y.domain.com.ex
      - z.domain.com.ex

    hostnames: "{{ sites|map('split', '.')|
                         map('first')|list }}"
    domains: "{{ sites|map('reverse')|
                       map('splitext')|
                       map('first')|
                       map('reverse')|list }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: hostnames
    - debug:
        var: domains
```

---

Q: ***"I need the second variable."***

A: Use Python slices. For example, split and flatten all items

```yaml
s: "{{ sites|map('split', '.')|flatten }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  s:
  - x
  - domain
  - com
  - ex
  - y
  - domain
  - com
  - ex
  - z
  - domain
  - com
  - ex
```

Then, select second variable with the step of 4

```yaml
sites_1: "{{ s[1::4] }}"
```

gives

```yaml
sites_1:
  - domain
  - domain
  - domain
```

This way you can create any combination you want. For example,

```yaml
sites_domns: "{{ s[1::4]|zip(s[2::4])|zip(s[3::4])|
                 map('flatten')|map('join', '.')|list }}"
```

gives

```yaml
sites_domns:
  - domain.com.ex
  - domain.com.ex
  - domain.com.ex
```

See [Understanding slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slicing).

Comment: Perfect, thank you so much.
what if I need the second variable of main domain as one value instead of a list.

Comment: A great answer!

Comment: Use Python slices. I added examples.